# Matching on tuple using comparison operator

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I would like to match on tuple pattern, but I can not find any solution how to match using comparison operators. My code is:

```
myTuple  match {       
      case (-1,-1,true) => ...       
      case (_>=0,-1,_) =>  ...
    }
```

This gives give compile time error.
I also tried to use if guard, but as I see it can not be applied this way:

```
 case (_ if _>=0,-1,_) =>  ...
```

Is my approach correct or should I solve this on an different way?
Thanks
Zoltan

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax is wrong, you should use guard as follows:

```
myTuple  match {       
  case (-1,-1,true) => ...
  case (x,-1,_) if x >= 0 =>  ...
  case _ => ... // default
}
```

There are a lot of good introduction to scala pattern matching on the web. Here is the first detailed one, I've found on google: [Playing with Scala's pattern matching](http://kerflyn.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/playing-with-scalas-pattern-matching/)